# Choosing positioning of a child node in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm adding nodes to a D3 tree layout at runtime but when the new child nodes are inserted, the original child is pushed over to the very left.  I would like the original child to be in the middle (or close to) of the group of children so that if the graph is something like :

```
                                   Parent

                                   Child C
```

adding additional nodes A,B,D, and E results in a graph like this:

```
                                   Parent

               ChildA     ChildB   ChildC    ChildD   ChildE
```

rather than this:

```
                                   Parent

               ChildC     ChildA   ChildB    ChildD   ChildE
```

If relevant, code for this update function is below:

```
function update(record_to_add, parent) {
                        if (nodes.length >= 500) return clearInterval(timer);

                        // Add a new node to a random parent.
                        var n = {id: nodes.length, Username: record_to_add.Username},
                                p = nodes[parent];
                        if (p.children) p.children.push(n); else p.children = [n];
                        nodes.push(n);

                        // Recompute the layout and data join.
                        node = node.data(tree.nodes(root), function(d) { return d.id; });
                        link = link.data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });

                        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                        });

                        // Add entering links in the parent’s old position.
                        link.enter().insert("path", ".node")
                                .attr("class", "link")
                                .attr("d", function(d) {
                                    var o = {x: d.source.px, y: d.source.py};
                                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                                });
                        node.enter().insert("text")
                                .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.parent.px);})
                                .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.parent.py);})
                                .text(function(d) { return d.Username; });

                        // Add entering nodes in the parent’s old position.
                        node.enter().append("circle", "g")
                                .attr("class", "node")
                                .attr("r", 10)
                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.parent.px; })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.parent.py; });

                        node.on("mousedown", function (d) {
                            var g = d3.select(this); // The node
                            // The class is used to remove the additional text later
                            console.log(d.Username);
                            if (d.id == null)
                            {
                                console.log("ASDgasd");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                try {
                                    downstream_length =
                                            DownstreamRecords[d.Username].length;
                                }
                                catch(err) {
                                    downstream_length = 0;
                                }

                                for (var i = 0; i < downstream_length; ++i)
                                {
                                    update(DownstreamRecords[d.Username][i], d.id);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                            var g = d3.select(this); // The node
                            // The class is used to remove the additional text later
                            var info = g.append('text')
                                    .classed('info', true)
                                    .attr('x', 20)
                                    .attr('y', 10)
                                    .text('More info');
                        });

                        // Transition nodes and links to their new positions.
                        var t = svg.transition()
                                .duration(duration);

                        t.selectAll(".link")
                                .attr("d", diagonal);

                        t.selectAll(".node")
                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.px = d.x; })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.py = d.y; });

                        t.selectAll("text")
                                .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.px = d.x + 20; })
                                .attr("y", function(d) { return d.py = d.y; });
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting the nodes? See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#sort).

Comment: What would the sort predicate be?  There is no order for the nodes, the can be in any order

Comment: The order in which you want them to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than using push for adding child use

```
arry.splice(index, 0, newObject);
```

so you can add new child on your selected position but you have put some validation like lenth or array and index point etc.

like this

```
if (p.children) p.children.push(n); else p.children = [n];
```

replace it with

```
 if (p.children){

    p.children.splice(0, 0, n);
     // or you can do some calculation according to number of child 
      available and made index
    //p.children.push(n);
}
 else{ p.children = [n];}
```